# How to set file upload directory by parent node content type and node id

Tags: 7, files

I am trying to set the upload directory for a file field to contain the content type (and node id) as part of the path.

The desired path for my public files field is `publication_documents/pub/content_type/node_id_of_node_this_was_uploaded_to/filename`

I have tokens installed, but it doesn't seem to offer me tokens related to the parent node in the upload directory setting:

[image: error message]

[image: File directory]

Slide 30 of [This slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/AcquiaInc/preventing-drupal-headaches-establishing-flexible-file-paths-from-the-start) seems to indicate that it is possible, but how can I do it?

In case it matters, I'm using the media and file_entity modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module should help you.
[image]

Comment: That seems like exactly what I need, but I still have one issue.  Is there a token or a way to get the machine name of the content type instead of the Human Friendly version.  My migration is already copying the files over using the machine names.

Comment: nevermind, found it! [node:content-type:machine-name]